# Issues While implementation of Saber Car API

Tags: sabre

I am sending bellow XML Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header><ns1:MessageHeader xmlns:ns1="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" ns1:version="1.0"><ns1:From><ns1:PartyId ns1:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">99999</ns1:PartyId></ns1:From><ns1:To><ns1:PartyId ns1:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">123123</ns1:PartyId></ns1:To><ns1:CPAId>H60H</ns1:CPAId><ns1:ConversationId>reefcube</ns1:ConversationId><ns1:Service ns1:type="OTA">Saber Car Shop</ns1:Service><ns1:Action>OTA_VehAvailRateRQ</ns1:Action></ns1:MessageHeader><ns2:Security xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"><ns2:BinarySecurityToken>Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/STSA!ICESMSLB\/STS.LB!-3542300499375769855!141112!0</ns2:BinarySecurityToken></ns2:Security></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><OTA_VehAvailRateRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" Version="2.4.0"><VehAvailRQCore QueryType="Quote" RPH="1"><VehRentalCore PickUpDateTime="2015-05-23" ReturnDateTime="2015-05-26"><PickUpLocation LocationCode="DFW"/></VehRentalCore><VendorPrefs><VendorPref Code="ZE"/></VendorPrefs></VehAvailRQCore></OTA_VehAvailRateRQ></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And getting following XML Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap-env:Header><eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1"><eb:From><eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">123123</eb:PartyId></eb:From><eb:To><eb:PartyId eb:type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">99999</eb:PartyId></eb:To><eb:CPAId>H60H</eb:CPAId><eb:ConversationId>reefcube</eb:ConversationId><eb:Service eb:type="OTA">Saber Car Shop</eb:Service><eb:Action>ErrorRS</eb:Action><eb:MessageData><eb:MessageId>9dc74d0f-27fb-4c94-b6d3-d1e290b63173@176</eb:MessageId><eb:Timestamp>2015-04-23T13:20:08</eb:Timestamp></eb:MessageData></eb:MessageHeader><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"><wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/STSA!ICESMSLB\/STS.LB!-3542284933698243327!161224!0</wsse:BinarySecurityToken></wsse:Security></soap-env:Header><soap-env:Body><soap-env:Fault><faultcode>soap-env:Client.InvalidAction</faultcode><faultstring>Action specified in EbxmlMessage does not exist.</faultstring><detail><StackTrace>com.sabre.universalservices.base.exception.ApplicationException: errors.xml.USG_INVALID_ACTION</StackTrace></detail></soap-env:Fault></soap-env:Body></soap-env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Action Code for Car Availability should be "OTA_VehAvailRateLLSRQ" as described below.

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/ground_transportation/search/car_availability